# What is the passé composé form of “arriver à faire qqch”?

Tags: constructions, auxiliaires

Would it be *j'ai arrivé à faire* or *je suis arrivé à faire*?

I know the normal form of arriver conjugates with *être* as auxiliary but I am not so sure about the other usage.

Answer (score 2):

*Arriver* is one of the small group of verbs that uses *être* as its auxiliary for the passé composé, as you've mentioned.

"Arriver à faire qqch" is no exception. Just because *arriver* is being followed by some additional words here, that doesn't change its grammatical nature. It's still being used in the passé composé in the context you're asking about, and so it still uses *être*.

So it would be "Je suis arrivé à faire qqch."